# Эффекты наложения при прозрачности

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте. Допустим, есть прозрачный контрол (или окно целиком). Сквозь него просвечивается все что под ним. Но можно ли каким то способом задать эффекты для прозрачности? Например, размытие. Или увеличение. Или подскажите как получить битмап из содержимого под?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший из классов эффектов WPF является `BlurEffect`. Он размывает содержимое элемента, как если смотреть на него через расфокусированную линзу. Степень размытия повышается увеличением значения свойства `Radius` (которое по умолчанию имеет значение 5).

```
<Button Background="Transparent" Content="Hello">
    <Button.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

Чтобы контент контрола не размывался можно попробовать сделать так:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Padding="20" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text inside a Border" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: А контент кнопочки оно тоже размоет?

Comment: @iRumba, да, контент тоже размоет.

Comment: А надо, что бы не размыло...

Comment: @MaximK, обновил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: Сойдет пока. Но что то мне в этом способе не нравится... Пока не пойму что. Возможно, дальше будет видно.

Comment: Для окна не подходит...

Comment: Почему? Что не подходит?

Comment: не размывает фон

Comment: Вы хотите на форму поставить какой-то фон, и размыть его?

Comment: @Lightness нет. Я хочу прозрачную форму с размытием, за которой будет виден рабочий стол, но чтобы контролы не размывались